Can 〜とか〜とか and “〜たり〜る” also be used to have the first items be examples of the last?
What I mean with that is that I can vaguely recall at one point having read that one can say say “「スパイダーマン」とか「スーパーマン」とか漫画が好き” to mean “I like comic books such as Spider-Man and Super Man,” rather than it meaning “I like things such as Spider Man, Super Man, and comic books,” with all but the last elements providing examples of the first. Same with say “ゲームをプレイしたり、映画を見たり、なにか楽しいことをしたい” being interpretable as “I'd like to do something fun such as playing video games or watching a film.” But I'm also not sure as to how accurate that is or whether I misremembered something, especially because I'd instinctively would use “「スパイダーマン」とか「スーパマン」とかの漫画” nowadays for that meaning.

I don't think seeing them as "last elements" is right.

の changes the meaning a bit:

AやBなどの漫画が好きです。
AとかBとかの漫画が好きです。
I like comic books like A and B.
AやBなど、漫画が好きです。
AとかBとか、漫画が好きです。
I like comic books, for example A and B.

The former is usually interpreted to mean that the speaker likes a certain genre of comic books exemplified by A and B, whereas the latter means they like manga in general. In the latter, I'm not sure how to explain the grammatical role of the examples part, but it functions somewhat independently (the same is true for your example of たり). The comma is not strictly necessary in Japanese, but it's usually better to use one.
Your example (スパイダーマンとかスーパーマンとか漫画が好き) seems a bit puzzling to me, because the two examples strongly suggest a certain genre (アメコミ) but the sentence structure suggests an interest in 漫画 in general.
Another example:

ホットドッグとかハンバーガーとかの食べ物が好きです。
→ I like Western fast foods!
ホットドッグとかハンバーガーとか、食べ物が好きです。
→ I'm a food enthusiast!

